# Passing variables to PHP script via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, onclick

I am truing to pass variables to a PHP script using onclick but obviously I am doing something wrong.

So..I have in my main page somewhere:

```
<img src="myImage.jpg" id="cart_icon"  onclick="addcart('100')">
```

and the addcart function:

```
function addcart(id){
    $.ajax({
          url: "add_item.php",
          method: "POST", 
          data: {prod_id : id}
        });
}
```

The add_item.php looks like this (just a simple example):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start(); 
if (isset($_POST['prod_id'])){$_SESSION['item_id']=$_POST['prod_id'];}else($_SESSION['item_id']='Not Set');
```

When I check the value of the SESSION['item_id'] I am getting 'Not set' instead of '100' 
Any thoughts? This is just a simple example. The actual code is more complex. Thanks

Comment: This example seems fine to me. Can you do `var_dump($_POST);` on the add_item page?

Comment: Have you tired using $_GET?

Comment: Also for the if/else you have the else in parentheses not curly brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your AJAX call looks incorrect because the method of the call needs to be defined via `type` and not `method`.

Read the documentation of [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

The correct call should be:

```
function addcart(id){
    $.ajax({
          url: "add_item.php",
          type: "POST", // notice the change over here
          data: {prod_id : id}
        });
}
```